# How can I get the value of property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This would filter which have em in background-position:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background-position').indexOf('em');
})
```

Now how can I get it's width and set in variables:

```
background-position: 2em 5em;
```

Here, first variable should get 2 and second variable should get 5 of returned filter.

Comment: where is your element selector? you need to target a single element

Comment: you get computed style, not as defined. Looks like a XY problem, so what are you looking for? Why would you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking how to parse a string. Your `filter` call will give you a list of elements that have "em" in the `background-position` property. To loop through those and get the values from each (remember, it's a list, there can be more than one entry on it), you'd do this:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background-position').indexOf('em');
}).each(function() {
    var match = $(this).css('background-position').match(/(\d+)em[ \t]+(\d+)em/);
    var first = match && match[1];
    var second = match && match[2];
    // Use `first` and `second`.
});
```

For example, if you have an element with the background position `"2em 5em"`, then `first` will be `"2"` and `second` will be `"5"` in that loop iteration. (If you want them as numbers, you can use `first = parseInt(first, 10)` or similar.)

---

As A. Wolff points out in the comments, at least some browsers will return pixel values rather than em values from the `css` function; similarly, I've seen Chrome return percentages if the element in question doesn't have a specific rule assigned. So your filter will, on those browsers, return no elements at all.

Here's an example that generalizes things a bit:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background-position'); // Any non-blank value
}).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), match, first, second;
    // Get the value, including units -- these may be "em", "%", or "px" (or others?)
    match = $this.css('background-position').match(/([\d.]+)([^ \t]*)[ \t]+([\d.]+)([^ \t]*)/);
    if (match) {
        first  = convertToEms($this, parseFloat(match[1]), match[2]);
        second = convertToEms($this, parseFloat(match[3]), match[4]);
    }
});

function convertToEms($elm, value, units) {
    switch (units.toLowerCase()) {
        case "em":
            // Already in ems, we're done
            return value;
        case "px":
            // 1em = the number of pixels in the font size
            return value / parseFloat($elm.css("font-size"));
        case "%":
            // You'll want to figure this out, it happens on Chrome with defaults
        default:
            // And you'll want to figure out what to do with units you don't know
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `.css('background-position')` return value in pixel? EDIT: at least in chrome/FF it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Rd6h4/

Comment: @A.Wolff: Okay, now I'm going a little bit crazy. Because it doesn't for me in the console, but it *does* in your fiddle (with the same browser). At first I thought it was because I was assigning directly (not inheriting from a style sheet), but that didn't make any difference. What the...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder think you might need to divide by 16 :p

Comment: @A.Wolff: Figured it out: I was working with a disconnected `div`. E.g.: `div = document.createElement('div'); div.style.backgroundPosition = "2em 5em"; $(div).css("background-position");` which gave me `"2em 5em"`. But as soon as I append that div to a document, I get back pixels instead.

Comment: I was just looking for the concept that you gave to me. It's okay with em as I'm working on that browser.

Comment: @Beneto: Or 20. ;-) But I think the premise of the question may be flawed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder css() returns computed style, this is how i see it

Comment: @A.Wolff: *If it can*, yes. With my disconnected `div`, it couldn't, which is what mislead me. :-)

Comment: @C-link not sure to understand your comment but i hope your are not just coding for your own browser, right?! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Em values are probably the most difficult values to wrap the ol' noodle around, probably because the very concept of them is abstract and arbitrary. Here's the scoop: 1em is equal to the current font-size of the element in question. If you haven't set font size anywhere on the page, then it would be the browser default, which is probably 16px. So by default 1em = 16px. If you were to go and set a font-size of 20px on your body, then 1em = 20px.

```
var em=$(element).css('background-position')/16;
```

[Soruce](http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/)

```
var div=$('body').css('font-size');
var posEm=$(element).map(function(){
    return parseInt($(this).css('background-position'),10);
}).get();
positonTopInEm=posEm[0]/div;
```

Comment: `/20` could you explain?

Comment: well it depends what browser and what you set the position as. 1em = 20px so 100px/20=5em. I think the standard might be 16px. http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

Comment: ahhh my bad. Thought they'd asked to get the em from the return rather than pixels.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder for me, `.css('background-position')` return value in pixel, so not so irrelevant imho

Comment: @A.Wolff: Yeah, if the browser sends it back in pixels, this would relate. And it certainly seems to do exactly that. +1 to Beneto.

Comment: still this answer is not correct, need some split() to get numerical values but that give a good idea of what could be done, so +1

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, @A.Wolff: Could even make the int a variable as `$('body').css('font-size');` that way you're dividing with the correct integer.

Comment: @Beneto good idea! Because i think on some device (retina?) 1em is not 16px. But beware, $(this).css('background-position') won't be parsed correctly if more than one property value is set. Should be tested though

Comment: @T.J.Crowder better idea?

Comment: @A.Wolff This might be a better idea?

Comment: @Beneto: No, you're still not splitting the string. And what makes you think the `font-size` of the `body` will necessarily relate to the element?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The body's font-size is equal to 1em. What string is there to split? background-position would return: `20 30`. In a string yes but parsed to an integer.

Comment: @Beneto: What if I've set a different `font-size` on the element? And quick, what does `parseInt("20 30")` return? Or `parseInt("20px 30px")` (as these are usually returned with the `px`)? (Also note that the values may not be integers.)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correclty what you're trying to do, you can use

```
$('*').each(function() {

  if($(this).css('background-position').indexOf('em') != -1){

    $(this).css('width','200')
  }

});
```